# DOJO: How to validate (required="true") selectOneMenu

Tags: dojo

How i can validate DOJO selectOneMenu (required="true") here is some dummy code.

```
   <select required="true" missingMessage="Ooops!  You forgot your gender!" 
name="gender" id="gender" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/?">
        <option disabled="true" value="">Select a Gender</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo provide 3 type of combobox  :

1. Select 
   It is simple combobox like select in HTML with no validation and not provide any search           facility inside select options.
2. ComboBox
   It is pure form of combobox and name as ComboBox again it will not provide any default validation but it provide search facility within its options.
3. FilteringSelect
   It is an advance form of select have default facility of validation and search facility. And it also has property to take value as input tag take value in HTML.

In dojo you can also try custom validation which is provided inside dojox library.
I hope it will help you.